# Quartz Composer mouse hover and scroll

Tags: scroll, hover, mouseover, quartz-composer, origami

I'm really new to origami and quartz. I've only spent a few hours on it today and am still a little lost.

I'm trying to show some interaction for a website in a web browser. What patch would I use to register a mouse hover on a button or window? More specifically I've attached a link to show what kind of interaction i'm trying to achieve ([Living Options section](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jq8n0iiqx1oxkt6/rvm_test.mp4?dl=0)).

Also *how do you use the mouse scroll patch?*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To register a mouse hover, you would use the setup pictured above. First you need to define a `Hit Area` (the area to be hovered). Plugged into this you need an `Interaction` patch. Finally, you need to define which kind of mouse interaction you want to track – in this case `Mouse Over`. You have have a number of options here:

1. Plug the `Mouse Over` output port into another patch, e.g. the `Text patch`.
2. Create a `Wireless Broadcaster` (pictured) to send the interaction anywhere else in your composition (via a `Wireless Receiver`).
3. `Publish` the output up **one layer**. To do this, hover over the desired port and hit 'p'. The output will now be available from the parent patch.